# Gutenberg Api-Fetch to Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, fetch, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm new with Gutenberg / WP and i'm trying to send data to database with my form block. I created a "subscribers" table on the database with this fn:

```
function register_subscribers_table() {

    //Connect to database
    global $wpdb;

    //Table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'subscribers';

    //Access character set and collation for the database
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
     ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta( $sql );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_subscribers_table' );
```

This code in my php file of plugin.

And i'm trying to send form data (email) to the database with javascript & React in my block scripts (view.js in block):

```
 const form = document.querySelectorAll(".my-form");

    Array.from(form).forEach(function(el){

    el.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      const data = new FormData(event.target);
      const result = data.get("email");

      // I need send the result to the database

      el.reset();
      })
    
    })
```

I tried api-fetch but i can reach the posts/pages only, no database. Is there a way to do it?